# what is "stack alignment"?

Tags: c++, data-structures, mingw, visual-c++, compiler-construction

What is stack alignment? 
Why is it used? 
Can it be controlled by compiler settings?

The details of this question are taken from a problem faced when trying to use ffmpeg libraries with msvc, however what I'm really interested in is an explanation of what is "stack alignment".

The Details:

- When runnig my msvc complied program which links to avcodec I get the
  following error: "Compiler did not align stack variables. Libavcodec has
  been miscompiled", followed by a crash in avcodec.dll.
- avcodec.dll was not compiled with msvc, so I'm unable to see what is going on inside.
- When running ffmpeg.exe and using the same avcodec.dll everything works well.
- ffmpeg.exe was not compiled with msvc, it was complied with gcc / mingw (same as avcodec.dll)

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Since others have explained what stack alignment is and why it is used, I just want to add my two cents regarding _"Can it be controlled by compiler settings?"_. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496045/why-is-my-stack-pointer-only-incrementing-in-multiples-of-16?lq=1)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Alignment of variables in memory (a short history).

In the past computers had an 8 bits databus. This means, that each clock cycle 8 bits of information could be processed. Which was fine then.

Then came 16 bit computers. Due to downward compatibility and other issues, the 8 bit byte was kept and the 16 bit word was introduced. Each word was 2 bytes. And each clock cycle 16 bits of information could be processed. But this posed a small problem.

Let's look at a memory map:

```
+----+
|0000| 
|0001|
+----+
|0002|
|0003|
+----+
|0004|
|0005|
+----+
| .. |
```

At each address there is a byte which can be accessed individually.
But words can only be fetched at even addresses. So if we read a word at 0000, we read the bytes at 0000 and 0001. But if we want to read the word at position 0001, we need two read accesses. First 0000,0001 and then 0002,0003 and we only keep 0001,0002.

Of course this took some extra time and that was not appreciated. So that's why they invented alignment. So we store word variables at word boundaries and byte variables at byte boundaries.

For example, if we have a structure with a byte field (B) and a word field (W) (and a very naive compiler), we get the following:

```
+----+
|0000| B
|0001| W
+----+
|0002| W
|0003|
+----+
```

Which is not fun. But when using word alignment we find:

```
+----+
|0000| B
|0001| -
+----+
|0002| W
|0003| W
+----+
```

Here memory is sacrificed for access speed.

You can imagine that when using double word (4 bytes) or quad word (8 bytes) this is even more important. That's why with most modern compilers you can chose which alignment you are using while compiling the program.

Comment: This explains very nice why an array of words should be aligned.  Because accessing a specific element would otherwise require two reads.  But in the example with the struck containing a byte and a word: If you read the complete struct then in both cases you have to read both words anyway.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe **" But words can only be fetched at even addresses. "** Why this needs to be true, can't the memory/stack pointer point to 0001 in your example and then read a word of information starting there?

Comment: @User10482, I will take 2 read actions in that case. And as such is slower.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Why is that? The machine can read memory in blocks of 2 bytes, with one read action, in your example (like 0000, 0001 or 0002, 0003). So if my address register is pointing to 0001 (odd address instead of even), then I can read 2 bytes from there (i.e. 0001 and 0002) directly in one read action, right?

Comment: So you are saying that it's a restriction put by the CPU manufacturer that the address must be even? @ToonKrijthe

Comment: @User10482 Go read the pdf 'What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory', page 7, Figure 2.7. Memory is not as you picture it in your head, its not stored as a line, its a Matrix, so you can read a whole row in one go , but if you are not aligned , you need 2 read access.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe could you please tell me how does the instruction `and rsp, 0xfffffffffffffff0` alling stack 16 bytes in AMD64 architecture.

Comment: @User10482 [might be useful](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/pa-dalign/)

Answer (score 13):

Some CPU architectures require specific alignment of various datatypes, and will throw exceptions if you don't honor this rule. In standard mode, x86 doesn't require this for the basic data types, but can suffer performance penalties (check www.agner.org for low-level optimization tips).

However, the [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instruction set (often used for high-performance) audio/video procesing has strict alignment requirements, and will throw exceptions if you attempt to use it on unaligned data (unless you use the, on some processors, much slower unaligned versions).

Your issue is **probably** that one compiler expects the *caller* to keep the stack aligned, while the other expects *callee* to align the stack when necessary.

**EDIT**: as for why the exception happens, a routine in the DLL probably wants to use SSE instructions on some temporary stack data, and fails because the two different compilers don't agree on calling conventions.

Answer (score 12):

IIRC, stack alignment is when variables are placed on the stack "aligned" to a particular number of bytes. So if you are using a 16 bit stack alignment, each variable on the stack is going to start from a byte that is a multiple of 2 bytes from the current stack pointer within a function.

This means that if you use a variable that is < 2 bytes, such as a char (1 byte), there will be 8 bits of unused "padding" between it and the next variable. This  allows certain optimisations with assumptions based on variable locations.

When calling functions, one method of passing arguments to the next function is to place them on the stack (as opposed to placing them directly into registers). Whether or not alignment is being used here is important, as the calling function places the variables on the stack, to be read off by the calling function using offsets. If the calling function aligns the variables, and the called function expects them to be non-aligned, then the called function won't be able to find them.

It seems that the msvc compiled code is disagreeing about variable alignment. Try compiling with all optimisations turned off.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1 byte, which is always at least 8 bits... not bytes. Alignment depends on compiler platform, and (x86, anyway) is generally 4byte for 32bit architectures, 8byte for 64bit archs.

Comment: Thanks, was a brainfart indeed on the size of a byte :P. I had picked 16 bytes as an arbitrary example, but using the smaller example makes it much clearer.

Comment: No, stack alignment is about maintaining the alignment of the stack pointer itself.  Single-byte local variables on the stack can be at any address.  If there's only one, then there will be padding before the next variable, because most ABIs align the basic types like `int` to their own width (natural alignment).  Only for arg-passing on the stack are single-byte objects padded to the "stack width" or slot (the size of a single `push` instruction).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, compilers don't typically align variables that are on the stack.  The library may be depending on some set of compiler options that isn't supported on your compiler.  The normal fix is to declare the variables that need to be aligned as static, but if you go about doing this in other people's code, you'll want to be sure that they variables in question are initialized later on in the function rather than in the declaration.

```
// Some compilers won't align this as it's on the stack...
int __declspec(align(32)) needsToBe32Aligned = 0;
// Change to
static int __declspec(align(32)) needsToBe32Aligned;
needsToBe32Aligned = 0;
```

Alternately, find a compiler switch that aligns the variables on the stack.  Obviously the "__declspec" align syntax I've used here may not be what your compiler uses.

Comment: Compilers *do* align variables on the stack to the alignment guarantees / requirements for that type specified in the ABI.  Normally that means natural alignment: alignment = width, so a 4-byte `int` gets 4-byte alignment.  Maintaining 16-byte alignment for the stack pointer itself makes it possible to align variables on the stack by 16, 8, 4, or 2 with no extra cost.