# How does strcat not overwrite the next variable?

Tags: c, memory, strcat

```c
char str[] = "some short string";
int a = 20;
strcat(str, "a very very long string");
printf("%d\n", a); // prints 20
```

If I understand correctly, `a` is added to the stack directly above `str`. But this should mean that when `str` is resized to take up more space, it should overwrite the memory space `a` is using. How does this still print 20?

Comment: str will not be resized by strcat(). You must provide adequate space to str:  char str[255] = "some..."

Comment: but if I print `str` at the end it will print the full longer version @ulix

Comment: "...at the end..." it is still undefined behavior.

Comment: How can `str` contain the long string without overwriting `a`?

Comment: The simplest situation is if `a` is located before `str` on the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `str` will not be resized. It just occupys the memory after `str` beyond compiler's comprehension. It may cause unexpected consequences.
2. [Understanding stack allocation and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4817473/13898468) There is some space after `str`. The size of space depends on various compilers. In my PC, the program does not print 20, but a meaningless number.

```
+-----------------+ high address
| <function info> |
+-----------------+
|       <a>       |
+-----------------+
|  <empty space>  |
+-----------------+
|gnirts trohs emos| "some short string"
+-----------------+
|                 | <- stack pointer
|                 | low address
```

3. Or another possibility, your compiler allocate `a` after `str`. Therefore, `a` can't be affected by `str`. The compiler decides the order of memory allocation.

```
+-----------------+ high address
| <function info> |
+-----------------+
|  <empty space>  |
+-----------------+
|gnirts trohs emos| "some short string"
+-----------------+
|       <a>       |
+-----------------+
|                 | <- stack pointer
|                 | low address
```

Comment: Another possibility is the compiler does not even allocate any space for `a` as it can replace it by its value `20` is the `printf` statement. Also insist on undefined behavior being **undefined** so nothing can be expected.

Comment: Yes, this is closely related to compiler optimizations. The right way is not to depend on undefined behavior.