# Why is my stack pointer only incrementing in multiples of 16?

Tags: assembly, x86

Using the following C code

```
void func() {
  int a=1,b=2,c=3;
}
```

Compiling using `gcc -S -O -o- myfile.c` I get the output

```
    .file   "myfile.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
.globl func
    .type   func, @function
func:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 1
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 3
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 4
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-20], 5
    leave
    ret
    .size   func, .-func
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here I would expect the third line after `func:` to be `sub esp,12` instead of `sub esp,16`. I played with different numbers of automatic variables in the function and found that it grows in increments of 16 bytes. Why does this happen? Does this happen on all platforms, or is it platform specific?

I'm currently running an Intel Mac with OSX, compiling through an Ubuntu (32-bit) VirtualBox guest using GCC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [GCC man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc), (bold emphasis mine):

> **-mpreferred-stack-boundary=num**
>
> Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to num byte boundary. If `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` is not specified, **the default is 4 (16 bytes or 128 bits)**.

Comment: And the reason why compilers do this is that some instructions accessing memorylocations *not* aligned get a performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks, between this answer and vidstige's comment I have the information I need :)

Comment: @vidstige @Martin: or they crash, even on x86 (see movaps, e.g.).

Answer (score 2):

That is very strange output.

Are you sure the c file wasn't:

```
void func() {
  int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5;
}
```

?

Otherwise why the lines

```
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], 4
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-20], 5
```

Comment: I agree with you, but that shouldn't be an answer. That is actually a question to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

x86_64 ABI requires the stack to be 16-byte aligned

[Stack allocation, padding, and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1061818/995714)

For 32-bit OS X then it does that because of SSE and some other reasons

[Why does the Mac ABI require 16-byte stack alignment for x86-32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612443/995714)