# Does the stack (memory segment) always save variables continuously?

Tags: c, memory-management

Let's say I'm writing a C program which has:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 5;
int *p = &a;
```

Will:

```
int k = *(p+1);
```

always give `k = 5`?

---

Formally:

Is this "continuous" property of the variables' address on the stack implementation-dependant? If not, is anything guaranteed (for example `&a < &b < &p`)?

(This simple test using gcc on ubuntu gives `k=5`, but other tests involving different types do not work)

Comment: if you want continuous memory, use an array allocation

Comment: I just wanted to get some more info on the stack segment. But thanks  anyhow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No... <strike>though it probably will on most platforms</strike>There's absolutely no guarantee that your code will yield 5. What you have is *undefined behaviour*, which may result in your program craching. Never rely on undefined behaviour, full stop.

Comment: "though it probably will on most platforms"... I don't think so. Often, `b` won't even be put on the stack, but just be held in a register - depending on its usage.

Comment: @glglgl: Fair point... will edit my answer. Just tried this code on my system, and got 5, too (slackware)

Comment: And on more complex functions (where you run out of registers), the life time of variables often does not overlap so two variables can share the same address.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ... depending on the optimization level. With `-O0`, you might get that result, with other levels, if unused, `b` will probably be optimized away.

Comment: Stack alignment is another example for how this undefined behavior is completely unreliable:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672461/what-is-stack-alignment